# Make background color change on hover after setting style using ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of words with a number (streak) assigned to each word. I set the background color of each word based on the number assigned to it using AngularJS's ng-style.

html

```
   <ul class="unstyled">
     <li class="tHi" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="getEdit(item.word)" ng-style="bgstyle(item.streak)">
       <span>{{item.word}} {{item.streak}}</span>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

javascript that is called from ng-style.

```
$scope.bgstyle = function (streak) {
    var red = 255;
    var green = 255-streak;
    var blue = 255-streak;
    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    var sColor = '#' + rgb.toString(16);
    return {backgroundColor: sColor};
}
```

This works, however, I would like the background to be highlighted when the mouse hovers over a word. I added a class "tHi" that normally would change the background on hover, but it is overridden by the added style.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rAyJ/) that demonstrates this issue.

Is there a better way to set the background than ng-style so that it corresponds to the number assigned to each word? Or is there a way to highlight when a user hovers over a word?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is one of the very few cases where I'd actually suggest using `!important` in CSS:

```
.tHi:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #9f9 !important;
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5rAyJ/1/).

Using the `!important` keyword essentially causes the rule to be applied regardless of the specificity of the selector (assuming that a more-specific selector doesn't *also* have the `!important` keyword, of course). It *does*, however, have the potential to make debugging quite difficult, if you, or your colleagues, forget about the use of the `!important`.

References:

- [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use `!important`, you can add the class dynamically using [ng-mouseover](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngMouseover):

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="getEdit(item.word)" 
    ng-style="bgstyle(item.streak)" ng-mouseover="hover($event)">
```

Then add to your controller:

```
$scope.hover = function(e) {
    angular.element(e.srcElement).addClass('tHi')
}
```

Manipulating the DOM in a controller is not "best practice".  A directive would be better.

**Update:** Here's a directive

```
myApp.directive('ngHover', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
       element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
          angular.element(element.children()[0]).addClass('tHi')
       })
    }
  }
});
```

`children()[0]` is used to apply the class to the span, not the li, so as not to conflict with the ng-style.

Use as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="getEdit(item.word)"
  ng-style="bgstyle(item.streak)" ng-hover>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/HYqgW/)

Comment: I like your answer as an example of using a directive and ng-mouseover. Thank you. Also, your answer made me realize something that did not occur to me before. The simplest solution would be to add the class 'tHi' to span and not to li. That way I don't need !important or a directive. Like you said it avoids a conflict with ng-style.

Comment: Great observation.  (And it avoids all that extra event binding and $watching.)

Comment: This is an entirely orthogonal comment, but if you're just applying a class for style, you can always use good ol' CSS and define :hover.

Comment: one question, why are you using angular.element(element.children()... if you can use element.children().eq(0).... ?

Comment: @Kalamarico, no good reason -- probably because I didn't think of using the shorter `eq(0)` way when I originally wrote my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found through a directive was the easiest way.

```
App.directive('attr', function(){
    return function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
            element.addClass('hover');
        }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
          element.removeClass('hover');
        })
    }
})
```